# problem with android simple drop down list

Tags: android, text

I have an app in android which uses an autocomplete for a query in the DB....The autocomplete entries are displayed in a drop down list ....

The problem is that the size of the text displayed in this drop down list is very big and don't know how to make it smaller:

This is a piece of code:

```
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent){

        Cursor c = getCursor();
        final LinearLayout ret = new LinearLayout(context);

        final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        mName = (TextView) inflater.inflate(
                android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, parent, false);


        mNumber = (TextView) inflater.inflate(
                android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, parent, false);

        ret.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

        LinearLayout horizontal = new LinearLayout(context);
        horizontal.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

        int nameCol = c.getColumnIndex(db.KEY_SURSA);

        String name = c.getString(nameCol);

        String number = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(db.KEY_DATE));

        mName.setText(name);
        mNumber.setText(number);

        horizontal.addView(mName, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        ret.addView(mNumber, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        ret.addView(horizontal, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        return ret;

    }
```

mName and mNumber are the text view used for displaying my DB content....but how I obtain them frm inflating  android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line I don't know how could I modify the text size...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are looking for? This would set the text size to 100dip, you could adjust the number to whatever you are looking for.

```
mName.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the singleLine attribute in the xml of each text view with declaring the drop down adapter to be custom.

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/info"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textColor="black"
        android:text="bla bla bla bla bla bla"
        android:singleLine="true" />
```